# Error using live USB to install Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Tags: boot, dual-boot, usb, live-usb

I'm trying to install Ubuntu in addition to windows 10 on my Acer Nitro 5 an515-52. I installed Rufus and created a live USB as per many tutorials. I have disabled secure boot and made the live USB the boot priority but instead of being greeted by GRUB the following error flashes on the screen for half a second after which windows continues to boot normally.

```
Reloc 12 Unknown relocation
Relocation failed; Unsupported
failed to load image; Unsupported 
start_image() returned Unsupported
```

I couldn't find a solution to this on any forums. This is my first time installing Ubuntu so any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Double-check that the ISO is valid. Check the SHA256 hash of it, and compare it to `5fdebc435ded46ae99136ca875afc6f05bde217be7dd018e1841924f71db46b5` (case doesn't matter). In PowerShell, run `Get-FileHash -Algorithm SHA256 theImageFile.iso` (using your filename, of course). If it gives something different than the has above, then you have an issue, and I'd suggest re-downloading the image. The hash is from [here](http://releases.ubuntu.com/focal/SHA256SUMS).

Comment: @cocomac i performed the verification and got `5fdebc435ded46ae99136ca875afc6f05bde217be7dd018e1841924f71db46b5` meaning the image should be fine

Comment: If the thumb-drive failed to boot; and the messages you gave are all you got (before other OS booted), then I'd blame the write to your installation media. In my experience about 5-8% of ISO writes to thumb-drive (*very large files*) fail, thus why the media verifies itself on boot; your system from description didn't succeed here, so I'd try booting it on another box (or two); one of a like type, then a different type - if it fails on those other (1 or 2) boxes then it's a bad write of ISO to your media. If it boots fine (only to "*Try Ubuntu*" not install) then it's not media & box specific.

Comment: You also didn't mention if you're asking about Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS Desktop, Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS Server etc.   Please be specific.

Answer (score 0):

Advise is  to check your usb-stick for bad sectors first.

If your usb-stick is damaged and you have no other/are not able to get another one then there is the option of installing Grub2Win. That is a Grub for Windows. In that program you can add the option of booting from an ISO.

The code should be
`menuentry "Ubuntu" {                                                                                                                                                                              insmod ext2                                                                                                                                                                                                      set isofile="/ubuntu-20.04.3.0-desktop-amd64.iso"                                                                                                                         loopback loop (hd0,7)$isofile                                                                                                                                                                      linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz boot=casper iso-scan/filename=$isofile noprompt noeject quiet splash toram initrd (loop)/casper/initrd }`

Assuming that your ISO-file is located in your rootdirectory replace hd0,7 with hd0,1 ( your windows bootloader is probably hd0,0 and your Windows partition hd0,1) and use the name of your ISO-file after 'set isofile'. It doesn't matter if you have a hdd, sdd or nvme drive, they are called hd by Grub. You can check your partitions in Diskmanager ( rightclick on startmenu or search for diskmanager/dskmgr ). In a Linux-based system they are called different ( there are no C or D drives but are called hd0,0 hd0,1 or if you have more drives hd1,0 etc. )

Set Grub as your default bootloader and you will be greeted after booting up with Grub with the option to boot from your ISO-file.